# How to show positive and negative series sum value for the stacked bar chart top and bottom column in Apache Echart.?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts

I have currently using Apache Echart (version - 15.0.2) in angular 15.

I have created a stack bar chart, here I have created a sum of series values, If I am getting positive value able to show the top based on the last index, but I getting negative value unable to show the bottom,
my expect result is if getting negative values need to show the bottom of stack bar chart column, below I have attached the print screen, please do needful.

**My Result :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjgkF.png)

**Except Result : **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VVSM.png)

Here need to show negative value bottom for the stacked bar chart.

**Source Code**

```
const series = [
    {
      name: 'Bing',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [60, 72, 71, 74, 190, 130, 110],
      avoidLabelOverlap: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Others',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [62, 82, 91, 84, 109, 110, -120],
      avoidLabelOverlap: true
    }
  ];


option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        
        name: 'yAxes',
        nameLocation: 'middle',
        nameGap: 25,
        alignTicks: true,
      },
  yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        name: 'yAxes',
        nameLocation: 'middle',
        nameGap: 25,
        alignTicks: true,
       
      },
  series: series.map((item:any, index) => Object.assign(item, {
      type: 'bar',
      stack: true,
      label: {
        show: index === series.length - 1 ,
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#ccc',
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = 0;
          series.forEach(item => {
            sum += item.data[param.dataIndex];
          });
          return sum

        }.bind(this),
      },
    }))
};
```

I am trying to below steps not working.

```
formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = 0;
          series.forEach(item => {
            sum += item.data[param.dataIndex];
          });
          sum > 0 ? item.label.position = 'top' : item.label.position = 'bottom'

          return sum

        }.bind(this),
```

**if getting positive value **

```
   label : { show : true, position : 'top'}
```

**if getting negative value **

```
   label : { show : true, position : 'bottom'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a transparent helper bar with `label: {position: 'bottom'}` to achieve the desired result.
[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtDA2ADAGmwCYBdfDAdiPwA5TyKBGfATkbMoBZbOPGWCjXCz4BmQUL5D8AWkZFcJEgG4AUKEiwIAVwC2ENPCQIAdLoQAHABQAnEAHc0APhh37JmwFM424J6tWYJ4AHlD4MMDaNl5gUACUzjBBoTAA1BFRMWEwuHFxahrQMAAWngA2Fp42AEIINoY6-maWAQBuCGXanuEAlmBwIQmoLgDeqjAwPQBmMFbtnZ4wTui5MGMTE15QUWA5ahMAvuOunts2uwCySMVmfSaWFmUAnoHaZWXhiMgYfQPBJHFVAdAaoQBYoD1wIZ1jAoCAQGUIRYAFxrY4TKA2HoAc2xVVRAHIEMEehACfh0TBiaSAAogPpQfFojYbKBPSqEiDFBBwBwEylHQ4UiZlTx4_qokYHYUwbFYuCSymiqZQQmiACk5MpWOxxVVMAJnE1MomACMQFA4bo1cbKRpkH0ADIIU3lVGYrrHaXHYIAQRJEEVLLZHINwCQYpANieWpZXwQqIwBIu4HJBoAKl00wSAOrebPp4rabMAMSx2YAykhK9owASyKpKWAELpPISnv7PGSTUkW55HSBwxDwITdD04HBRbGNs3WwBxSyoogAVh7HRxYHTPWAAGtA7CbJ6hccOwGg6z2W2DfMsz3Z1eCaeu9OJveB0PIWBR-PJ54X7350XGAVzXMoNy3Xd9w9TwvRlCAqh6LtE0pGEWXvQlqj6bF_wxS9CVNOocJgaAEF3QkK08OpgGKGAAFEwGxPo_x7CZPF0CxuQgUlzxZCYpkHbR9wJeCsWfSlj14oxkFReNmmsNxEjcDBFDiFiqVaek4GdV0ygAeVaKoyiA6Ce29FlUJnPtCV0qBShsbtxNhPCDQImwiJIsiDQoqiaPoxigiItiOIQLj9wsll-MiISRMQslHLM3j4xk4w5NsBxFIcDB2FUxyEA08dtPKfTDOMw9ukcySjJ0njeK5Bx3TKtSJgsEAuOHL8DThCwiL4qNzEtJkplrYB2tmCw6hbBJwt40UtD0Bo9AgDBxpsFsTHjABJfoQhUCqNmmWZGhgAAeHIpr2lkth2GAACIbv2SSNkFR7NlOa7GgeyTnpZb6YASiZppDB9XKI1yFxRGA5DUpKSnKSoajqNSuNFWJCWgojQDKKNURuzEEEgFbPFiG61Kqt1mUeur7AarompgFq2s_fCLStHqYH4mx-sZGxUSGsARs_MaJt0c6XpFU5iPm9BGiWla1s27b_k-x6DqsI7TtWabJKu85Jd0ZWvouk4zl2O6Dae-KBWOEggWUIA):

```js
const data = [[60,62],[72,82],[71,91],[74,84],[190,109],[130,110],[110,-120]];
const sums = data.map(row => row.reduce((next, current) => next + current, 0));
const helperBar = sums.map((value, index) => {
  if (value >= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.min.apply(null, data[index])
})

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],

    name: 'yAxes',
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameGap: 25,
    alignTicks: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: 'yAxes',
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameGap: 25,
    alignTicks: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Bing',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: data.map(row => row[0]),
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Others',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: data.map(row => row[1]),
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
            label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = sums[param.dataIndex];
          if (sum < 0) {
            return "";
          }
          return sum;
        }
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      barGap: -1,
      data: helperBar,
      silent: 'true',
      color: "transparent",
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = sums[param.dataIndex];
          if (sum < 0) {
            return sum;
          }
          return "";
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Alternatively you could put all labels on top by using the the formatter of both series based on the sign of the sum.
[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=CYQwLiAEC8kNpwGwAYA0kDsAmdGCMuALOngJxqR4DMFeeyAuukjpAByukHvGXKkl66ALR4sjBgG4AUNID2ABzABLOQDsYkAN7TIkMHLkAbFQoBc23Xv0AnZQHN7AUxsWA5CAAeygM5vUVnpevgAKcspqYC4WOtbWYACeCk7uPgAWIMByAO5ugZAAvlYFAXpGTs5qwDElVvZ21ZZx5QBmYO5UAKT--Xb2ae2QboTdpdYARnJgBgC2HaP5AMbqEBEAMiDjTkYWYDYArk7FY54Agt4-MfmJye6L4BVyNgk9caAQFnBuALLq_kMAFUO_zcAHUnMAQQC0vsQQAxOwggDK4GR-zUbiYsjiahAMxSQwS5ycfjGelx-LWcnuKnU7hmymAwHKr2sFKcAHEQOZIFgAKxkyAgIwONQA5SLADWl1sh2OViJFyucRuBLcADdhcDBez3IqSazyXinFSaao1PTGcynIbIOyuTz-YLhaLxVKZXs5XpanofC5lCTPvlYnE7cb3AAhCL2W16VXucYgGyxyA-CBS9xIpxJxZpSAAUTU9giNsFeicMwUGR8vmVob0LWp-xlbj9dgN-W9Zcg7xAFl7cEY3ZA6vCwA2WyMAHl1S4jNzdgcnN355O6_X0jlF4du3oFHIa7SLUMDAoUw2njNwFFXJAWujFkfIAAKBRJvEASia9es5TAqf2GZNGQGQf2sXsADpGxsfMQFzZ9lCiIDoAAPm_MDfUAyAAGpYEQis4DfGw8Qg3sAEkqicTwpE7UMCg_UCMOUFoXx8LCAB5IGQL8QwwyAbCcMB9hsDQ2JmRiwKKPiBKEkTIAAInkiS6NoqTrB9axeLZcMhinMA0hcUlaPjIZE2Tbs0zgyVM2zGxcwLIsSxTCsqxAGsZS0uJG0WZtUn9Dt6w0t5wD7HsQrgPAsXrEcxwnbYZznBdZWXWj61XbZ11DTdsm3FKwP3Q9zXcU9zzvS9r2iO8HyfV93xmHjUt_QSAOQrjlPrSDoNg-D8OQtDPJ_MScLwpDCLq0iQoo4AqJovj6Pa0NmNYjiuIavi9Bk4SNEUha4jUsDNrksTdsKVT8jUhhpAKSQgA):

```js
data = [[60, 72, 71, 74, 190, 130, 110], [62, 82, 91, 84, 109, 110, -120]];

option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'shadow'
    }
  },
  legend: {},
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],

    name: 'yAxes',
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameGap: 25,
    alignTicks: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    name: 'yAxes',
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameGap: 25,
    alignTicks: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Bing',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: data[0],
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = 0;
          data.forEach(item => {
            sum += item[param.dataIndex];
          });
          if (sum < 0) {
            return sum;
          }
          return "";
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Others',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'Search Engine',
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: data[1],
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
            label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: function (param) {
          let sum = 0;
          data.forEach(item => {
            sum += item[param.dataIndex];
          });
          if (sum < 0) {
            return "";
          }
          return sum;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtDA2ADAGmwCZ8BGIgXXwwHYSAOEgWgGYAWK20_ATm6Z65ONNvnqiilaqUFlcPMqU6kWBUqQJNyLZRvxaiBIjooBuAFChIsCAFcAthDTwkCAHT2EABwAUAJxAAdzQAPhgAwLc_AFM4W2Bonx9gWz8YsCh8GDBogA8oAEpQ7LzYAGoYFLTojKzcAoKLK2gYAAtogBsvaL8AIQQ_Umc7Rw9vJIA3BA7baKyASzA4PKLUMIBvcxgYeYAzGB8pmeiYEPR6mE3t7ZioVLAYXAttgF8t8Oi7vweAWSRWjyLNzeLwdACePjAtg6HSyiGQGEWy1yFAK5heaOasHaXR6_T8RGGDggY18h2mswWSxWxSuO325OOMAAPOcinSbp97o9njA3pyvg94QhEdSUVFYvFEslUulMiV8qsNu9tnsDjl8qdHuyVddbtyqnKYBUNVBea9dfrvpVZTUze8XnVGui0eYQF4oPNwM46VAQCAOp6vAAuS66qB-eYAcyjPVDAHIELl5hB4_hdUmUwAFECLKBxsPXa5QMHdBMQVoIOBBeO6_l89PbDrRWNLUPrR3vKORuDt3XN3ZQBMsACkact0daQ5g8bYY8b1wARiAoH77MP57qrMhFgAZBCLzqhiOzB0L3IAQWTED7RZLZZnwCQLZAfjB46LwtDGHjP3AaZnAAVWYAPjAB1WJQMA1pbFAgAxSNQIAZSQZDbDAeMqHMXUwAQexogTMEr2iVMF22XD8N3EAn09cAE3seY4DgZsP2uCjogAcW8UMiAAVjImBpmjMBAPmYAAGsbxgE9ojPd4iOvW9i1LAiZyOECBPYwjiNInC8OiKiaK9MB6MY5jolY8j9K4kMYD4gShKjESxMk48_FPV4FwgHp5hI79dQ5Nj9ITXpFijSzlIfeNFwGCLtmgBAJITJDogGYBWhgABRMAo0WCyBO2aJ7C8SsIBTJSi22XZqNsKT428yMSNrSqG11bYvxcZBSX8IJigiDAhAKArBImXM4H3Q8OgAeQmHoOm46T3LmOthsCqz8ITABNToOhrYb71U6LYuGhKkpnFK0oy7LcpyOKYCKkqEDKqS1uuaqUjqhrfNTNrWpajrhW6iI-qCDAlCG36EFGxiJs6Ga5oWmSBM7ItXq0mcpqgdo_F0lqDoTGK_Du07xOS1K_HSrKcryu6HtK8rCxamB3tq8sfKa36UcqgHXCB3q1nCUHKAhlqobG2Hptmvx5tspGVoC378ZnQm7sJmzQy0YaOpxbo-gGbhfrK5sMgTGS7tAXa_FDAAiCMEEgLwBjta3hvmyaKsqisgjcylfu2LwQDK2iTOVlc1zuqrX08VcC12dDgGDg5Hb8PCdSZ65mxsBwiUcDBk7wtxhQASTFMw_euNUfBGFltUZ9OBW5EZzSZ-t06tB5ret5ui1b65e657ZXqVo6ieGtWFs137tc6XX8RIQ35mN6d4zN4aLdfG27Ydp2Mhd363aPOvPdab3Ft99OA6D4zTfdCPmajpB8yt5n48Tnx8_sNP68zmBq_QEYIB5wGAXYupdu6VUrtXMIFxXotXbr_Bw4Ce7lwbtaTuSC-SczrO8Cg6JTBAA) for multiple helper bars.

Comment: I tried dynamic stack bar like, I have using 3 ro 4 stack data 
like   :  **const data = [[60,62,12],[72,82,-34],[71,91,-90],[74,84,22],[190,109,11],[130,110,-123],[110,-120,23]];**

Can you help positive values are top of stack bar negative values are bottom of stack, bar.       

Expect result is not coming for above data values, I have attached link [link] (http://surl.li/lcozs)

Comment: You can use a second transparent helper bar. I added an example to the previous answer.